# Which accounting software is compatible?

Tags: accounting

I was wondering what accounting packages, if any are compatable with CiviCRM.  I'm in Australia also if that helps.

Comment: Thanks for your feedback. Do either of these solutions work with the free version of Civi?

Comment: CiviCRM is open source so the software is always free. You may pay for hosting and other services, but not for CiviCRM itself.

Answer (score 3):

There is a batch export in csv that works for many packages, a .iif that works for QuickBooks desktop, an extension that integrates with QuickBooks online Australia, and an extension that supports Microsoft Dynamics.

Comment: Thanks joe, I’m not sure what an .iif is but I’ll do some more research. We’re thinking of migrating to quick books online, so I guess it’s probably the best option. How do you go about getting the extension?

Comment: .iif is Intuit Interchange Format, and is something designed by and for QuickBooks. Here is the QBO Australia extension repo: https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.civiquickbooks. You might want to contact Agileware (or us if they're busy) for help if needed getting it installed and going.

Comment: I’m still trying to find out about this extension for quick books of which you speak. Quick books australia say this: “ at 18:50, May 10: Usually, applications like Civi integrate through our API so data flows through automatically. I would actually talk to Civi directly if you can because if I am honest, I am not sure how the file extentions work”.so I’m a bit confused still.

Comment: I would encourage you to contact Justin at Agileware re install assistance for https://github.com/agileware/au.com.agileware.civiquickbooks

Answer (score 2):

We have built an integration package with Xero which is available and explained [here](https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civixero). Xero is available in [Australia](https://www.xero.com/au/features-and-tools/accounting-software/).

The integration means that both Contacts and Transactions can be pushed or pulled to civicrm, and the civi Financial Types can be set to match the Chart of Accounts in civicrm.

Comment: Ah, yes. Sorry I forgot.

Comment: I’m still trying to find out about this extension for quick books of which you speak. Quick books australia say this: “ at 18:50, May 10:
Usually, applications like Civi integrate through our API so data flows through automatically. I would actually talk to Civi directly if you can because if I am honest, I am not sure how the file extentions work”.so I’m a bit confused still. Also Xero Australia say there’s no integration.

Comment: You say "Also Xero Australia say there’s no integration". The extension is here https://github.com/eileenmcnaughton/nz.co.fuzion.civixero  if you need assistance with setting this up then you can contact Fuzion about professional support but the documentation covers everything that is required. I can flesh out more about how it works if you want to contact me directly peter.davis@fuzion.co.nz.